# TDE error when attempting to encrypt a datafile

Tags: linux, oracle-11g, transparent-data-encryption, standby

I'm encountering error

```
ORA-28374: typed master key not found in wallet
```

when attempting to run

```
alter database datafile '+DATA/testdb/datafile/users.2514.1233355332' encrypt;
```

against an 11g database on Linux. Basically it's not possible to encrypt any datafile.
The sqlnet.ora file is correct and pointing to the vault.
If anyone could please direct me to a check list of what could be wrong it would be greatly appreciated.

Also (just guessing) if the original primary was encrypted but not the standby and then the standby became the primary and the old primary dropped. Could that lead to the error above? How could such a situation be rectified? Is it just a case of deleting the old endpoints in the key vault? Thank you.